# Strategy to Show a Set is Smallest

Tags: measure-theory

In the context of measure theory,

if one wants to show, say the Borel set, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open intervals, is the strategy to show an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ containing all open intervals always contains $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$? Are there other strategies?

Reference:
$\textit{Probability and Measure Theory}$ (Robert B. Ash and Catherine A. Doleans-Dade), Harcourt/Academic Press, 1999.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are saying. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra just _is_ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the open sets. Are you asking about the general strategy to show that one $\sigma$-algebra contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra? What is your definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @EliBashwinger Hi, thanks for the response. I am asking how to show a set is the small set containing something, as a general strategy. In this context, it is the Borel set being the smallest sigma-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ containing all open intervals.

Comment: Yes, you prove that if $\mathcal{A}$ is any $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open intervals, then it must also contain every element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Technically, you should also show that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ *is* a $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open intervals, but I'm assuming this is already known.

Comment: Well, usually you just define the collection to be the smallest set containing things of a specified type. This is defined to be the intersection of over all collections containing those things. In the case of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, it is just defined to be the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the open sets, which would just be the intersection over all such $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: these are quite helpful. Can you formalize as an answer? I will select it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankSwanton Okay. I did just that. Let me know if there's anything related that you'd like me to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the request of the OP, I will try to collect all of the thoughts expressed in the comments. Speaking very generally and therefore somewhat vaguely, if you want to define the smallest collection containing "things" of a specified type, just define it to the intersection of all the sets containing those "things". To be slightly more precise, let $I$ be the collection of all those sets containing those things; then $\bigcap_{A \in I} A$ is the smallest set containing those things. Of course, lurking in the background is question of whether the indexing set $I$ is empty or not.

In the specific case you present, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing the open sets; i.e., it is the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra. And one can, for example, show that the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by showing that every open set is Lebesgue measurable.